# Check If String Input Is Not Equal To An Array of Strings

Tags: java, arrays

My current issue is checking how to create a condition to output Invalid Input when the user's input is not equal to any of the Strings in a defined array, and to continuously ask for new input until it is a valid option.

Code:

```
public class GameMenu {
       static String choice;
       int userOption = 0;

       public void printMainMenu() {
              [...] /* Other code that prints out menu */
              checkIfGuessComputerNumberIsChosen();
       }

      private void checkIfGuessComputerNumberIsChosen() {
              Scanner menuInput = createNewScanner();
              choice = menuInput.nextLine();
                   /* This code goes through the array of valid input */
              for(; userOption < validGuessComputerNumberOptions().length; userOption++) 
                      checkIfChoiceEqualsValidOption();
      }                  

      private void checkIfChoiceEqualsValidOption() {
              if(choice.toLowerCase().equals(validGuessComputerNumberOptions()[userOption])) {
                   PlayGame();  
              }
      }  

     private String[] validGuessComputerNumberOptions() {
             String[] inputOptions = {"a", "b", "c", "d"}; // List of input options
             return inputOptions;
     }

}
```

I want to be able to create another method that asks the user for input each time it does not match a String from the array found at validGuessComputerNumberOptions();

I have tried some code but I continue to get an array index out of bounds error.

Not Working Code:

```
 private void checkifGuessComputerNumberIsChosen() {
         Scanner menuInput = createNewScanner(); // createNewScanner is a defined method in the code
         choice = menuInput.nextLine();

         for(; userOption < validGuessComputerNumberOptions.length; userOption++) {
                   checkIfChoiceEqualsValidOption();

         while(!choice.toLowerCase().equals(validGuessComputerNumberOptions()[userOption])) /* If it is not equal to string */ {
             choice = menuInput.nextLine();
         }
}
```

Specifically, what is the best way to find whether the String is not equal to an element in the array of valid inputs, then prompt the user to enter their input again. Also, feedback about the structure and functionality of the code is appreciated. Note that the valid input "a", "b" [...] are example valid inputs, and not actual.

Comment: What you'r asking isnt exactly clear. Can you give us an example of input and expect output/ actual output?

Comment: Maybe you need to replace `for(; userOption...` with `for (userOption = 0; userOption...`. If this does not help you, please provide a complete stack trace.

Comment: @Marvin I have a global variable userOption = 0; so I assumed that was fine to have.

Comment: It's fine for the first run, but you're never resetting it.

Comment: @JesseShellabarger I expect the program to go through every valid string in the array, then if the user's input is not equal to any of the Strings in that array, then it will print "Invalid Input: Enter valid Input: " until the user enters a String found in the array validGuessComputerNumberOptions();

Comment: What makes a string "valid"?

Comment: The valid strings are found in the array inputOptions that is called with the method validGuessNumberOptions() - that returns the array of Strings containing the valid input.

Comment: Then it seems to me Alex has an acceptable solution

Comment: Alex's code is inefficient; I want to maximise readability and efficiency by having one array to loop through so that any valid inputs can easily be added to the array for valid input. Using his method would mean I would have a lot more code by adding and comparing each individual valid input.

Comment: @JesseShellabarger An alternative way of doing this is if(choice.equals("a") || choice.equals("b") || choice.equals("c")); But instead of doing that, I want all the choices in one array, then an variable to loop through the array and compare choice with each String in the array. If it matches, do some code. Else if it not equal to a String in the array, ask user to input new number.

Comment: If you're defining a valid input as one thats in the array, you'll never need to add another...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a method to do this then use it in your `while loop`:

```
public boolean checkInput(String input)
{
    String[] inputOptions = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
    for(String i : inputOptions)
    {
        if(input.equals(i))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

while(!checkInput(choice))
{
    choice = menuInput.nextLine();
}

//After this loop choice will be equal to a b c or d...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider switching to a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) object to store your candidate Strings.

You can then use the contains() method in ~ constant time to check if the String is a match.

```
HashSet inputOptions = new HashSet<String>();
inputOptions.add("a")
inputOptions.add("b")
inputOptions.add("c")

if (inputOptions.contains("a")) {
    //do something
}
```